# What's In A Name?

Tags: movies

I've found a list of movie names, but I have no idea what the movies are about and I've never seen them before. Based on their names and my imagination, Ive guessed the genre and written a pitch for the movie from what I imagined they are about. I've included the decade of each movie's release to help you narrow down the names. Can you figure out all 7 names?

#### List

1. Documentary 1990's / 2010's
   A company decides that all of its shipped product are unfit for consumer use and request that every one of them is pulled off the shelves
2. Fairy Tale / Drama 1980's
   Once upon a time there was a princess who lived in a castle and she had long hair and she was blonde
   and she went into the forest to get some flowers and she found some flowers and she liked them and she
   smelled them and she brought them back and she put them in a vase and she looked at them and she admired
   them and she wanted some water for them so she went to the lake for some water and she saw some fish so she watched them swim for a bit then she went home and she realized she forgot her water so she went back and she...
3. Apocalyptic Sci-Fi 1930's
   A massive power outage along the Pacific Coast cripples the area and cuts off all forms of communication with
   people in the region
4. Math Documentary  2010's
   Mathematicians struggle to determine what happens to the function $f(x)$ defined to be
   $\pi \text{ if } x\ge0$
   $142 \text{ if } x\lt0$
   as x proceeds to 0.
5. Science Documentary 1980's
   Theoretical physicists discuss what, if anything, could have existed before the Big Bang, in a thought-expirement
   taking place on a 0-dimensional realm.
6. Dystopia Sci-Fi 2000's
   In a futuristic society where efficiency and productivity are worshipped ideals, people's worth is determined
   by their contributions to society. Once members have reached a point where they can no longer work, they are culled.
7. Health Documentary 1990's
   Doctors and health experts explain how renal failure can be combatted by the miraculous process of dialysis,
   which filters blood through a machine in lieu of normal kidney function.

Comment: #5 could be "Point of No Return" (1993), but this does not fit with the 1980s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > Total Recall
2. > The NeverEnding Story
3. > All Quiet on the Western Front
4. > Limitless
5. > The Land Before Time
6. > No Country For Old Men
7. > Blood In, Blood Out

Comment: number 4 might be life of pi

Comment: @SirParselot: I'll add your answer, and make this a community wiki.

Comment: @JulianRosen x is the position in the number 3.142 and x = 0 at the point and the decimal points are negative and the farther to right x moves the closer to 0 it is. also x refers to your life. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with "cutting pie", as the digit 3 is cut from pi=3.142 to produce 142?

Comment: I think #5 might be Point Break, but that was from the 90's

Comment: I was thinking #5 was Weird Science, but I'm not sold on it.... Just a random thought.  Or maybe The Abyss.

Comment: Masters of the Universe for 5?

Comment: The numbers pi and 142 were chosen arbitrarily for # 4. In fact, I originally had pi and 42, but thought that might lead to Life of Pi, so I added a 1 in front. The two numbers could have been anything really (as long as they aren't equal). Instead of the numbers in particular, focus on what the mathematical implications of x going to 0

Comment: The Thin Red Line for #7?

Comment: #5 is The Land Before Time

Comment: @GordonK How does "0-dimensional realm" fit in?

Comment: I'm thinking Blood In, Blood Out for #7

Comment: @Roland Okay, I concede that's a better title.

Comment: @JulianRosen: Time is often considered the fourth dimension.  So to say "before time" means it lacks the three dimensions of space, plus the 4th dimension of time.

Comment: Limitless for #4?

Comment: "Vertical Limit" would be perfect for #4 if not the wrong decade.